# AjaxControlToolkit.dll not working on windows azure

Tags: azure

Following dlls are not working when I deploy my asp.net application in azure:
1. DropDownCheckBoxes.dll
2. AjaxControlToolkit.dll

They work perfectly in the non-cloud application deployed on the server as well as local.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain why you think these assemblies are not working in Windows Azure? Are you having issues in a web role or in a web site?

Most issues occur because the assembly is not included in the package. Could you try the following for both assemblies:

1. Right click the assembly
2. Select **Properties**
3. Change **Copy Local** to **True**

Redeploy the application.

Comment: Thanks Sandrino for the quick response.

Comment: We did chaged the property copy local to true. This is happening only for third party dlls. The native dlls of the application are working fine.

Comment: What error are you getting? Check your logs (diagnostics manager) or try to connect through RDP and verify the event viewer (Application log).

Answer (score 0):

Checked the "Remove additional files at destination" checkbox when publishing it to Azure and it will work. I had the same problem, none of the other solutions work. Here is the thread I found the solution in also, so simple but who would've known! Also I did not have to uninstall and re-install, all I did is check the checkbox during publishing:

[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/e29cc03b-c822-4ba9-b044-51107c367848/ajaxcontroltoolkit-is-not-working-when-deployed-to-azure?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/e29cc03b-c822-4ba9-b044-51107c367848/ajaxcontroltoolkit-is-not-working-when-deployed-to-azure?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/e29cc03b-c822-4ba9-b044-51107c367848/ajaxcontroltoolkit-is-not-working-when-deployed-to-azure][1]